# Android Compose Canvas producing unexpected BlendMode results

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I'm looking to clip an image by approximately a quadrant of a circle to get the following affect:

[image: Goal]

My initial thought was to use `BlendMode` in a `Canvas` using `drawWithContent`. However, I'm finding that all the `BlendMode`s that I've tried either just show the square image or show a square image with an opaque circle drawn over it. For *both* `dstIn` and `srcIn`, for example, I see:

[image: Result]

Source code:

```
GlideImage(
    modifier = Modifier
        .requiredSize(158.dp)
        .graphicsLayer(compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen)
        .drawWithContent {
            val radius = size.width - 28.dp.toPx()
            drawContent()
            drawCircle(
                blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn,
                color = Color.Transparent,
                radius = radius,
                center = Offset(radius, radius),
            )
        },
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    model = model.imageUrl,
    contentDescription = null,
)
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't wok you apply BlendMode to region only available to circle not all of the pixels in Composable. Because of that it won't be applied intersection or section where is not intersection of both.

If you are able draw image with Painter or ImageBitmap you can do it like this

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun BlendModeSample() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
    ) {

        val image = ImageBitmap.imageResource(R.drawable.landscape1)

        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(135.dp)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
                }
        ) {
            val radius = size.width - 28.dp.toPx()

            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Red,
                radius = radius,
                center = Offset(radius, radius),
            )

            drawImage(
                image,
                dstSize = IntSize(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt()),
                blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If that's not an option you can get difference of a rectangle and circle with paths and use that shape as mask using BlendMode.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun BlendModeTest() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(135.dp)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
                }
                .drawWithCache {

                    val radius = size.width - 28.dp.toPx()
                    val path = Path()
                    val pathCircle = Path()

                    if (path.isEmpty) {
                        path.addRect(
                            Rect(
                                offset = Offset.Zero,
                                size = size
                            )
                        )

                    }

                    if (pathCircle.isEmpty) {
                        pathCircle.addOval(
                            Rect(
                                center = Offset(
                                    radius, radius
                                ),
                                radius = radius
                            )
                        )
                    }

                    path.op(path, pathCircle, PathOperation.Difference)

                    onDrawWithContent {
                        drawContent()
                        drawPath(path, Color.Transparent, blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn)

                    }
                },
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.landscape2),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `ImageBitmap` approach doesn't quite fit my need due to constraints with how I need to use `GlideImage` to download a resource from an API, but the `Path`s approach worked like a charm! Major thanks @Thracian.